# I have that error when making a map request to the url

Tags: function, dictionary

```
const DisplayTable = (id, firstName) => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        obtenerDatos()
    }, [])

    const obtenerDatos = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/users",)
        const { users } = response.json();
        setUsers(users)
    }
    return (
        <div className="row">


            <ul>
                {
                    setUsers.map((item) => (
                        <li key={item.id}> {item.firstName}</li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
```

I have the error of the img, that the .map is not a function,
I'm wanting to make a request to that url and it throws me that .map error I attach the code[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR0vC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeiRh.png)

Comment: Think you meant to use `users.map(...` instead of `setUsers.map(...`

Comment: ^^ To expand on @IainShelvingtons comment --  `const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);`  Use the value on the right to SET the state .. Uee the value on the left to GET the state ..